# perforce P4 not working when called from vim

Tags: gvim, perforce

when calling p4Edit from vim like this : :!p4 edit /data/test.py

i get an error : test.py - file(s) not in client view.

but when sending the same command from the terminal everything is working well. can anyone help? I tried searching the web for an answer, they all lead to some configuration in the perforce GUI which is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you have opened the file in [g]vim you can use that directly through '%'.

```
!p4 edit %
```

The error suggests you to check the path your are providing to perforce as this doesn't exists in client view.